# Rendering telephone links in HTL based on input from a Rich Text widget

Tags: aem, xss, sightly, tel

I have a component using the Rich Text Edit widget (`xtype="richtext"`) in my project that's used across the entire site as the default text component.

The users would like to be able to insert phone links using the `tel` URI scheme into the text entered using this component.

The dialog allows them to do so but when the contents of the Rich Text Edit are rendered in Sightly/HTL later on, the `html` context is used:

```
{$text @ context='html'}
```

Once this is done, the value of my attribute is ignored.

The HTML stored in the repository is:

```
 <a href="tel:04242424242">Call us!</a>
```

And what's actually rendered on the page on the author instance is:

```
 <a>Call us!</a>
```

on the publish instance, the tag gets removed altogether because of the link checker.

Changing the context to `unsafe` causes the `href` to render but it's not a solution I'm willing to accept. The component is used in a lot of places and I want to be sure the XSS protection is sufficient.

Is there a way I can affect the way the `html` context in HTL treats telephone links?

I tried adding an extra regular expression to the overlay of `apps/cq/xssprotection/config.xml`:

```
<regexp name="onsiteURL" value="([\p{L}\p{N}\\\.\#@\$%\+&amp;;\-_~,\?=/!]+|\#(\w)+)"/>
<regexp name="offsiteURL" value="(\s)*((ht|f)tp(s?)://|mailto:)[\p{L}\p{N}]+[\p{L}\p{N}\p{Zs}\.\#@\$%\+&amp;;:\-_~,\?=/!]*(\s)*"/>
<regexp name="telephoneLink" value="tel:\+?[0-9]+"/>
```

and further on:

```
<attribute name="href">
    <regexp-list>
        <regexp name="onsiteURL"/>
        <regexp name="offsiteURL"/>
        <regexp name="telephoneLink"/>
    </regexp-list>
    <!-- Skipped for brevity -->
</attribute>
```

but that doesn't seem to affect the way the Sightly/HTL escapes strings in the `html` context.

I've also tried overlaying the Sling xss rules located in `/libs/sling/xss/config.xml` but had no luck either.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two xss protection config files:

1. `/libs/cq/xssprotection/config.xml`
2. `/libs/sling/xss/config.xml`

Sightly is using the second one, which means that you need to overlay it at path `/apps/sling/xss/config.xml`

What is worth mentioning is that new configuration seems to be applied only after restart of your aem instance.

Comment: Tried overlaying the one in `/libs/sling/xss` as well but it doesn't seem to work. There may be something else I'm missing though. I'll try the restart.

Comment: Yup, that started working when I restarted the instance. Cheers :)

Comment: @toniedzwiedz This answer is not wrong. It is one way of enabling the `tel:` links. But my recommendation would be to look at the `LinkChecker` configuration. The `href` in your phone links is probably removed by the link checker. You can configure a list of appropriate _Special Link Prefixes_ like `tel:` etc. and then the Link Checker will not remove links with those prefixes anymore. With this you won't have to use an overlay.

Comment: @Jens `LinkChecker` is the first thing we have checked and is the first step you need to do - without updated LinkChecker configuration link wouldn't work even in `unsafe` sightly / HTL context

Comment: @Jens yup, the way I understand it both steps are required.

Comment: I'd say you only need to change the LinkChecker configuration. No need to overlay xssprotection.

Comment: I tried overlaying the first one as per a [aem forum thread](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__iaoq-i_see_antisamyconfi.html), that also works. Not clear about the role of both.

Comment: @Jens Your suggestion is correct. My same issue was resolved by Link Checker