# AEM Rich Text Editor stripping international tel links containing +

Tags: aem, rte, tel, stripping

AEM RTE will allow you, at first, to make a `tel:` link using a `+` such as this:

`tel:+83493439343`

This will work fine. No problems so far.

But, when you go and edit the same RTE component, the `tel:` link will be stripped from the editor and be removed completely when you next save the component.

This only happens when the `tel:` link contains a `+`. If the `tel:` link is just numbers or numbers and spaces this issue does not occur.

At first I thought this was a link checker issue, so I tried adding some regex and a special link prefix as seen here:
http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2015/05/aem-6-sp2-handling-custom-protocol-in-link-href-in-rte.html

I even added a `tel:+` link prefix to no avail.

I have concluded that this must be an issue with the RTE but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.

Comment: I've seen something similar happen years ago so it's hard to tell, but it might be the same issue. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535342/rendering-telephone-links-in-htl-based-on-input-from-a-rich-text-widget

Comment: Have you found a solution?